# Android Studio: App doesn't start in emulator "Unfortunately ..app.. has stopped"

Tags: android, emulation

made a percentage calculator but it wont show up in emulator and before it starts u it just says "Unfortunately ..app.. has stopped"
Can someone advise me on what am doing wrong here?

Java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void ButtonClick(View v)
{

    EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    EditText p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percent);

    TextView r = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    double num1, num2, ans;
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString());
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(p.getText().toString());
    ans = 0;
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bt1)
        ans = num1 * num2 / 100;
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bt2)
        ans = (num1 * num2 / 100) + num1;
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bt3)
        ans = (num1 * num2 / 100) - num1;

    r.setText(ans + "");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/perccal2">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt1"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bt1"
    android:onClick="ButtonClick" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt2"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bt2"
    android:onClick="ButtonClick" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt3"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bt3"
    android:onClick="ButtonClick" />






<EditText
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="210dp" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/percent"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="247dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="165dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    />
```

LogCat:

```
    05-02 13:50:26.690    2300-2300/? E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError 
      "Failed to allocate a 138883260 byte allocation with 1048576 
      free bytes and 63MB until OOM"
      05-02 13:50:26.691    2300-2300/? D/skia﹕ --- 
     allocation failed for scaled     bitmap
      05-02 13:50:26.694    2300-2300/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
      --------- beginning of crash
      05-02 13:50:26.717    2300-2300/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.bluewhale.percentagecalculator, PID: 2300
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
       ComponentInfo{com.bluewhale.percentagecalculator/
      com.bluewhale.percentagecalculator.MainActivity}:  
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:
     Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at  
     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at 
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
    (ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error 
    inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at 
      com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView
    (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at 
        android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView
            (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView
            (AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.bluewhale.percentagecalculator.MainActivity.onCreate
           (MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at 
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                
       android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                 at 
         android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
               (ZygoteInit.java:899)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                at   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance
    (Constructor.java:288)
                at   
     android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView
     (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView
      (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView
      (AppCompatActivity.java:106)
              at com.bluewhale.percentagecalculator.MainActivity.onCreate
      (MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at 
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
      (ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
       Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 138883260 
      byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at 
    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at 
    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at 
    android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream
    (Drawable.java:973)
            at   
    android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView
        (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView
    (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView
    (AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at 
     com.bluewhale.percentagecalculator.MainActivity.onCreate
    (MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
    (Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
   (ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
    (ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800
    (ActivityThread.java:144)
            at     
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
      (ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
      05-02 13:50:26.728    1241-1289/? W/ActivityManager﹕
     Force finishing activity com.bluewhale.percentagecalculator/.MainActivity
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you close RelativeLayout tag in XML file properly? Because from what I see here it's not closed properly. Use </RelativeLayout> at the end of your file. Or is it just a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 138883260 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
```

You are attempting to allocate 138883260 bytes (~132MB) for the image you are trying to use for the `android:background` of the `RelativeLayout`. You do not have anywhere near that amount of heap space. Please use a smaller image, or use something other than a bitmap for the `RelativeLayout` background, or do not use a background on this `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @mrBlue: That is the size on disk. What matters is the size when the image is decoded.